# dpkg-query -L and dpkg -c?

Tags: dpkg, ios

I was installing my own package and found out that the installation fails with the following message:

```
dpkg: error processing archive io.c0ldra1n.classiccover_0.0.7-443+debug_iphoneos-arm.deb (--install):
 unable to create '/Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover.storyboardc/UIViewController-pVI-TE-B7r.nib.bundle/C.dpkg-new'
(while processing './Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover.storyboardc/UIViewController-pVI-TE-B7r.nib.bundle/C'): No such file or directory
```

So I looked into the directories, I ran dpkg-query -L to check what was actually installed.

```
/.
/Library
/Library/Application Support
/Library/Application Support/ClassicCover
/Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle
/Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover
/Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover.storyboardc
/Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover.storyboardc/UIViewController-pVI-TE-B7r.nib
/Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover.storyboardc/LOU-EB-wT9-view-aob-HL-njf.nib@
/Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover.storyboardc/pVI-TE-B7r-view-ySh-E6-Ils.nib
/Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover.storyboardc/albumTracksViewController.nib
/Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover.storyboardc/Info.plist
/Library/MobileSubstrate
/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries
/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/ClassicCover.dylib
/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/ClassicCover.plist
```

Here I noticed that an additional text was added to the original file, and the file name was corrupted. Nonetheless, dpkg -c gave me:

```
drwxr-xr-x c0ldra1n/staff    0 2017-12-27 20:59 .
drwxr-xr-x c0ldra1n/staff    0 2017-12-27 20:59 ./Library
drwxr-xr-x c0ldra1n/staff    0 2017-12-27 20:59 ./Library/Application Support
drwxr-xr-x c0ldra1n/staff    0 2017-12-27 20:59 ./Library/Application Support/ClassicCover
drwxrwxr-x c0ldra1n/staff    0 2017-12-27 20:59 ./Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle
-rwxr-xr-x c0ldra1n/staff 470336 2017-12-27 20:43 ./Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover
drwxr-xr-x c0ldra1n/staff      0 2017-12-27 20:59 ./Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover.storyboardc
-rw-r--r-- c0ldra1n/staff    968 2017-12-27 20:59 ./Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover.storyboardc/UIViewController-pVI-TE-B7r.nib
-rw-r--r-- c0ldra1n/staff   9994 2017-12-27 20:59 ./Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover.storyboardc/LOU-EB-wT9-view-aob-HL-njf.nib
-rw-r--r-- c0ldra1n/staff   4885 2017-12-27 20:59 ./Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover.storyboardc/pVI-TE-B7r-view-ySh-E6-Ils.nib
-rw-r--r-- c0ldra1n/staff   1039 2017-12-27 20:59 ./Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover.storyboardc/albumTracksViewController.nib
-rw-r--r-- c0ldra1n/staff    329 2017-12-27 20:59 ./Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover.storyboardc/Info.plist
drwxr-xr-x c0ldra1n/staff      0 2017-12-27 20:59 ./Library/MobileSubstrate
drwxr-xr-x c0ldra1n/staff      0 2017-12-27 20:59 ./Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries
-rwxr-xr-x c0ldra1n/staff 129040 2017-12-27 20:59 ./Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/ClassicCover.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x c0ldra1n/staff     51 2017-12-27 20:59 ./Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/ClassicCover.plist
```

Which has the correct names.

Any idea of why this would happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `/Library/` isn't a top level directory under root. I'm not sure if `dpkg` has some built-in safeguards to stop one doing this, or if there is something else, but regardless, you are clearly doing something non-standard here. Can you give a little background about what your software is, and how you created the deb?

Comment: Pathnames like `/Library/Application Support` and files with a `.plist` suffix suggest an Apple ecosystem: macOS or iOS. The .deb package name suggests some software for jailbroken iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

The error message refers to a directory with the name

```
/Library/Application Support/ClassicCover/ClassicCover.bundle/ClassicCover.storyboardc/UIViewController-pVI-TE-B7r.nib.bundle/
```

(note the extension ".bundle" at the end of the name) while the `dpkg -L` command does not contain a directory with the above name.

So in order to install a file into the directory with the above mentioned name, the directory has to exist first. Which it doesn't. You need to create it first.